# Why FileInputStream is much faster then BufferedInputStream with the same buffer size

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

Here are two pieces of code like this:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(tmp);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while (is.read(buf) > -1) {
}
```

and

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmp),1024);
while (is.read() > -1) {
}
```

It seems from `BufferedInputStream` source code that they will cost the same time, but actually the first way runs much faster (166ms vs 5159ms on a 200M file). Why?

Comment: Because you're making `fileSize/1024` method invocations in the first case, but `fileSize` method invocations in the second case. You may not be doing anything different in terms of the actual IO operations, but invoking a method isn't free.

Comment: Also, potentially, you're not doing the measurements of time in a way which gives meaningful numbers.

Comment: Your test is invalid. Try running the same code in both tests apart from the File/BufferedInputStream. You're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java.

Comment: Because `is.read()` reads **one** character while `is.read(buf)` reads **1024** bytes. Also `is.read()` is `synchronized` which might make a difference.

Comment: Actually ,the BufferedInputStream instance helped me reducing the IO operations,it also made `fileSize/1024` method invocations in the second case.

Comment: No. Actually it made `filesize` method invocations. No two ways about it. It performed `filesize/8192` *system calls,* which is another issue altogether.

Comment: You didn't ask it but it can be interesting: By using elements of java.nio package instead of java.io you can achieve quite serious performance improvements.

Comment: @pcjuzer Your evidence or authority for that statement? NIO is more *scalable.* Not necessarily faster at all. The biggest performance gain I have ever seen via NIO file handling is 20%, which is hardly 'quite serious'.

Comment: @EJP I have experiences: I reimplemented a java.io solution to NIO and it became much faster (like 10x). It was about copying file content with GUI feedback. I guess it was faster because of the non-blocking nature of NIO. So yes, not the NIO is faster in itself, it just lets other code to run while doing I/O operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileInputStream#read(byte b[])` will read the multiple bytes into `b` every call. In this case `1024`

`BufferedInputStream#read()` will read one byte every call. Internally `BufferedInputStream` will use a buffer of size `1024` to copy data from the stream which it wraps, however, you are still performing far more operations than you have to.

Try using the `BufferedInputStream#read(byte b[])` method and you will notice comparable speeds to that of `FileInputStream`.

Also as noted by [OldCurmudgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823393/oldcurmudgeon) the `BufferedInputStream#read` method is synchronized:

```
public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
    if (pos >= count) {
        fill();
        if (pos >= count)
            return -1;
    }
    return getBufIfOpen()[pos++] & 0xff;
}
```

To show you an example of how much overhead this can be, I made a small demo:

```
public class Main {
    static final double TEST_SIZE = 100000000.0;
    static final double BILLION = 1000000000.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testStandard();
        testSync();
    }

    static void testStandard() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i =0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((endTime - startTime)/ BILLION  + " seconds");
    }

    static void testSync() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i =0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
            synchronized (Main.class) {}
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((endTime - startTime)/ BILLION  + " seconds");
    }
}
```

On my computer the synchronized calls took around 40 times longer to execute:

```
0.13086644 seconds
4.90248797 seconds
```

Comment: @EJP even when specifying the buffer size as 1024?

Comment: @flakes I think `the far more operations` is not enough to make that big difference.

Comment: @Cherokee my pleasure :)